# Windowed function/pivot way to aggregate different values of the same column into different columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a hierarchy of tables:

- `GrandParentFoo`, which has zero or more
- `ParentFoo`, which has zero or more
- `ChildFoo`

`ParentFoo` and `ChildFoo` both have a `Status` column with a total of 4 possible statuses:

- Pending (1)
- Active (2)
- Paused (3)
- Complete (4)

I am trying to write a query that gives me a rollup for any particular `GrandParentFoo` along the following lines:

- GrandParentFooId
- Total ParentFoos
- Total ParentFoos Pending
- Total ParentFoos Active
- Total ParentFoos Paused
- Total ParentFoos Completed
- Total ChildFoos
- Total ChildFoos Pending
- Total ChildFoos Active
- Total ChildFoos Paused
- Total ChildFoos Completed

I was starting down the path of:

```
select
    gp.GrandParentFooId,
    count(distinct pf.ParentFooId) as TotalParentFoos,
    sum(case pf.Status 
        when 1 then 1
        else 0 end) as TotalParentFoosPending
```

...when I realized this was going to give me an inflated count where multiple `ChildFoo` records existed on the `ParentFoo` records.

Do I have to write this out as a series of CTE's, or is there a cleaner, simpler way to do this?  It seems like a pivot or windowed function of some kind would work here, but I can't conceptualize it.

Comment: To avoid inflating the ParentFoo counts, you might do a UNION of the ChildFoo counts over the ParentFoo counts, and then SUM both sides of the UNION.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One relatively simple method uses conditional aggregation with `count(distinct)`:

```
select gp.GrandParentFooId,
    count(distinct pf.ParentFooId) as TotalParentFoos,
       count(distinct case when fp.status = 1 then pf.ParentFooId end) as parent_pending,
       count(distinct case when fp.status = 2 then pf.ParentFooId end) as parent_active,
       count(distinct case when fp.status = 3 then pf.ParentFooId end) as parent_paused,
       count(distinct case when fp.status = 4 then pf.ParentFooId end) as parent_completed,
       count(distinct c.ChildId) as num_children,
       count(distinct case when fp.status = 1 then c.ChildId end) as child_pending,
       count(distinct case when fp.status = 2 then c.ChildId end) as child_active,
       count(distinct case when fp.status = 3 then c.ChildId end) as child_paused,
       count(distinct case when fp.status = 4 then c.ChildId end) as child_completed
from grandparentfoo gp left join
     parentfoo p
     on gp.GrandParentFooId = p.GrandParentFooId left join
     childfoo c
     on p.ParentFooId = c.ParentFooId;
```

Notes:

- `COUNT(DISTINCT)` is probably not needed for the children.  `COUNT(c.ChildId)` is probably sufficient.
- For larger data, I would suggest a more complex query to avoid the `COUNT(DISTINCT)`s.

Comment: Hmm... so null values will fall out in a COUNT DISTINCT, and you're left with just legit counts huh?  I will try this.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs . . . `count(distinct)` -- as with all aggregation functions -- ignore `NULL` values.